# FullCalendar appears behind backdrop with higher z-index

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make some events of FullCalendar appear in front of a backdrop that I have created but I'm unable to despite changing the `z-index` and I'm not sure why.

I have managed to get the whole calendar div in front of backdrop but I can't seem to target one event and set the z-index.

I don't have that much experience with modals and backdrops - did I miss out on a CSS property?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      right: "prev,next"
    },
    slotDuration: "00:05:00",
    slotLabelInterval: "00:15:00",
    contentHeight: "auto",
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    eventDurationEditable: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [{
      title: "Test Entry",
      start: "2017-12-18T01:00:00",
      end: "2017-12-18T02:00:00"
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.print.css');
#calendar {
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}

.fc-event {
  z-index: 20;
}

#backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="backdrop">
</div>
<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYwrqq

Comment: What part do you mean? The date?

Comment: I've checked your codepen and calendar is clearly in front of backdrop... What makes you think its not?

Comment: Its not behind your backdrop, the thing is your background of calender tag is transparent so it makes you think that the date is behind. If you set a background to the calender div, you'll see its infront of the backdrop.

Comment: @Highdef Alright I see, i still struggle to get the event in front of the backdrop however without having the full calendar in front. Codepen updated to illustrate.

Comment: You've set your backdrop z-index to 20 that's why its infront. Just add a z-index and background to the calender class and it works fine.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJjmmE

Comment: I'm still unable to get just the event in front of the backdrop, I attempted this  `fc-event { z-index:20` in updated codepen. I want the calendar behind the backdrop but the event in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, update how you desire:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      right: "prev,next"
    },
    slotDuration: "00:05:00",
    slotLabelInterval: "00:15:00",
    contentHeight: "auto",
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    eventDurationEditable: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [{
      title: "Test Entry",
      start: "2017-12-18T01:00:00",
      end: "2017-12-18T02:00:00"
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.print.css');
#backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#calendar {
  width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fc td,
.fc th {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="backdrop">
</div>
<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

Comment: Still attempting to just get the event in front of the backdrop and the remainder of the calendar behind like I initially attempted to!

Comment: Too excited my apologies